# How To Synchronize A field From subpanel with A field of his parent

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm quite new to Sugarcrm, so sorry if I am asking something stupid.

I have built 2 modules:

- Order Module
- Stone Module

http://postimg.org/image/6qabtru3t/

The relationship between both is, One To Many (One Order to Many  Stones). Accordingly, each record of Order Have A subpanel of stones (You can see it in the picture Attached). I want to synchronize A field from order with every change of a field in the subpannel (You can see it circled in red) - Price field at parent should be the sum of all same fields at subpanel.

So, I tried to use logic hooks like this:

```
$hook_array['after_relationship_add'] = Array();
$hook_array['after_relationship_add'][] = Array(1, 'after_relationship_add_hook', 'custom/modules/abc_Module_Order/HookHandler.php','class_after_relationship_add_hook', 'func_after_relationship_add_hook');
```

but it seems to go nowhere. What should I do? Use Ajax? Other Way To do logic hook?

Help would be highly appreciated, Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path. Also make sure to handle after_relationship_delete for when a Stone gets removed from an order.

Just for simplicity's sake I'd redefine your logic hook to:
custom/modules/abc_Module_Order/logic_hooks.php

```
$hook_array['after_relationship_add'] = Array();
$hook_array['after_relationship_add'][] = Array(1, 'update_order_addition', 'custom/modules/abc_Module_Order/HookHandler.php','HookHandler', 'update_order_additional');
$hook_array['after_relationship_delete'] = Array();
$hook_array['after_relationship_delete'][] = Array(1, 'update_order_removal', 'custom/modules/abc_Module_Order/HookHandler.php','HookHandler', 'update_order_removal');
```

Then in your custom/modules/abc_Module_Order/HookHandler.php file you would define the update_order_addition and update_order_removal functions that takes the price of the Stone and updates the order appropriately.

Comment: it is not working, I have done it, and additionly, in file custom\modules\abc_Module_Order\HookHandler.php:

<?php 
class HookHandler
{
    function update_order_additional($bean, $event, $argument)
    {
        // TODO
        die ("Hello from function update_order_additional");
    }

    function update_order_removal($bean, $event, $argument)
    {
        // TODO
        die ("Hello from function update_order_removal");
    }
}
?>

but its still doesn't work.

Comment: egg, something else that i missed?